# Is there a way to run GCP workflows locally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-workflows

Recently I started working with GCP workflows, and functions. We are using serverless framework for the functions and we can run them in our on computers with the command `serverless invoke local --function <function_name>` so we don't have to spend cloud executions.

What I'm looking now is if there is a way to do the same thing with GCP workflows, to run them in our own computers instead of invoking them inside the cloud.

I already read the resources from google and from many different articles but I still not find the trick (if it actually exists)

Comment: It's one of the top request of the Alpha tester (including me) of the product. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 2):

Today, there is no emulator for Cloud Workflows. But if you can afford to deploy your cloud functions on GCP, Cloud workflows has a [generous free tier](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/pricing#free_usage): 5000 steps for free